# MISRA rule 13.6 explanation needed

Tags: c, lint, misra

Rule 13.6 states that : The operand of the sizeof() operator should not contain any
expression which has potential side affects.I am at a loss to determine how an operator
with side effects will affect the outcome of sizeof() operator.
Can anybody explain with this example ?

```
void f(int32_t n)
{
    size_t s;
    s = sizeof(int32_t[n]); //Compliant
    s = sizeof(int32_t[n++]); //Non Compliant
}
```

Or can anybody give an example of a more understandable example and explain with that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression that is input to the `sizeof` operator is not evaluated. Only the type of the expression is deduced and used as input to the `sizeof` operator. Which means that, in the case that is non compliant to MISRA, `n++`, `n` **will not** be incremented. As this is somewhat counter-intuitive, MISRA recommends not to use expressions with side effects to avoid errors.

Comment: s/non compliant case/compliant case/

Comment: @wildplasser I find it to be correct. The non-compliant case is the one with the post-increment operator where counter-intuitively `n` doesn't get incremented.

Comment: It could be a bit ambigious. "[non] compliant" := compliant to **the standard**, or compliant to **MISRA** ?

Comment: Neither case is non compliant to the C standard. The second one is to MISRA as the comment in the example code says. But OK I'll clarify.

Comment: It is actually incremented by all major C99 compilers. See https://godbolt.org/z/5E79xje64

Answer (score 0):

The `sizeof` operator is a special case, usually it is only evaluated at compile-time and replaced by a constant. Meaning that any side effects ("code") inside the operand of `sizeof` will actually not get executed. Examples of such bugs:

```
sizeof(i++) // Bad! i will not get incremented
sizeof(i=j) // Bad! i will not get a new value
sizeof(func()) // Bad! The function will not get called
```

(There is one single exception when `sizeof` is evaluated in run-time, and that is when the operand is a variable length array type.)

The MISRA document provides a good rationale which explains all of this. If you read the fine print, there is even an exception for `volatile` variables, since the mere presence of such a variable in an expression introduces a side effect (reading the variable).

Comment: Yeah i remember the exception with the volatile as well. But could not get the whole idea of this side effect thing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @NishrinTrunkwala There is a formal definition of the term side effect in the C standard 5.1.2.2.3 "Accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function that does any of those operations are all side effects, "